# how to changes my variable from seconds to minutes

Tags: php, mysql

in my code below i subtract the previous date of the user john in the field name date_time
from the current date CURRENT_TIMESTAMP the variable $newdate echo the answer in seconds only how can i make it to display from seconds to minutes from minutes to hours then hours to days

```
$query1 = "
    SELECT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - date_time) AS dnew, date_time
    FROM user
    WHERE name = 'john'
";
$result1 = mysql_query ($query1) or die('query error2');
$line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1);

$newdate = $line[dnew];

echo "$newdate";
```

Comment: Using the `/` and `%` operators.  Simple math.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query1 = "
    SELECT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - date_time) * 60 AS dnew, date_time
    FROM user
    WHERE name = 'john'
";
```

use math ( * 60)